# taking out specific indexes from array

Tags: python, numpy

I have and array which I am trying to slice/split, small part of the array is as follow:

```
[(2008, b'2-room',  82000, 107000) (2008, b'3-room', 135000, 211000)
 (2008, b'4-room', 223000, 327000) (2008, b'5-room', 305000, 428000)
 (2008, b'3-room', 142000, 160000) (2008, b'4-room', 211000, 253000)
........
 (2019, b'5-room', 409000, 510000) (2019, b'2-room',  86000, 128000)
 (2019, b'3-room', 165000, 194000) (2019, b'4-room', 244000, 295000)
 (2019, b'5-room', 336000, 383000)]
```

```
dataprice = np.loadtxt(price,skiprows=1,usecols=(0,2,3,4),dtype=[('financial_year','i8'),('room_type','S8'),
                                                                ('min_selling_price','i8'),('max_selling_price','i8')]
                       ,delimiter=",")
list2019 =[]
list_rest=[]
for y in dataprice['financial_year']:
    if y == 2019 :
        list2019.append(???)
    else:
        list_rest.append(???)
```

I would like to take out rows that have 2019 only, is there a specific code to take out those rows?

Comment: if `dataprice` is a numpy array, you can use fancy indexing by doing `dataprice[dataprice['financial_year']!=2019]`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the comment to the question by @Tim Roberts, using fancy indexing can help:

```py
mask = dataprice['financial_year']==2019
list_2019  = dataprice[mask]
list_rest  = dataprice[~mask]
```

Comment: That only gets the year.  It doesn't get the rows.